# vbscript regex replace headache

Tags: regex, vbscript, replace

I have a text file I'm trying to process with vbscript, it looks like this:

```
111 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
222 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
333 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
444 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
555 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
666 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
```

What I want is to remove the carriage returns and tabs, commas and 'yes' (or the regex "\t,\t,\t\t,Yes\t,Yes") to give this output:

('111','222','333','444','555','666')

I'm using this code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
'chr(010) = line feed chr(013) = carriage return
strNewText = Replace(strText, "\t,\t,\t\t,Yes\t,Yes" & chr(013) & chr(010), "','") 

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

This isn't giving the desired output however, If I take the ""\t,\t,\t\t,Yes\t,Yes" &" out of the replace it removes the carriage returns, which is fine but I also need the commas tabs and 'yes' removed, as well as having a (' at the start and ') at the end. I'm guessing it's the way I've used the regex but I've not used much vbscript so I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hunting down what you don't want, it's easier and less errorprone to concentrate on what you want:

```
  Dim sExp   : sExp   = "('111','222','333','444','555','666')"
  Dim aLines : aLines = Array( _
      "111 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes" _
    , "222 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes" _
    , "333 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes" _
    , "444 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes" _
    , "555 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes" _
    , "666 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes" _
  )     
  Dim sAll : sAll = Join( aLines, vbCrLf )
  WScript.Echo sAll
  Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Global    = True
  reCut.MultiLine = True
  reCut.Pattern   = "^\d+"
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute( sAll )
  If 0 = oMTS.Count Then
     WScript.Echo "Bingo A!"
  Else
     ReDim aNums( oMTS.Count - 1 )
     Dim nI
     For nI = 0 To UBound( aNums )
         aNums( nI ) = oMTS( nI ).Value
     Next
     Dim sRes : sRes = "('" & Join( aNums, "','" ) & "')"    
     If sRes = sExp Then
        WScript.Echo "QED:", sRes
     Else   
        WScript.Echo "Bingo B!"
     End If
  End If
```

output:

```
111 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
222 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
333 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
444 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
555 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
666 ,   ,       ,Yes    ,Yes
QED: ('111','222','333','444','555','666')
```

Annotations:

I use an array to build my string to process (**sAll**). Your string (**strText**)
comes from a file. So:

```
  Dim sAll : sAll = Join( aLines, vbCrLf )
  ==>
  Dim sAll : sAll = objFile.ReadAll
```

The string is parsed by an RegExp (reCut), its pattern **^\d+** looks
for a sequence (**+**) of digits (**\d**) at the start (**^**) of a line (not
the whole string; that's why the MultiLine attribute is set to True).
The result of .Execute is a Match Collection (oMTS), containg Matches.

To make the the concatenation of the expected result easier, the
values of the Matches are copied to an array (aNums).

The `"('" & Join( aNums, "','" ) & "')"` expression combines the array's
elements using the separator (combinator?) **','** - to complete the result,
we need just a suitable head **('** resp. tail **')**.

Comment: QED!!! :) Fantastic way of doing it, I don't understand the code at all though - can you add another line in showing where I read my text file into the array?

Comment: I'm getting a wrong number of arguments error when I try to write the output? using this line of code:
`strNewText = Replace(sAll, sRes)`

Comment: Replace takes 3 arguments (see your own code). But I don't see any reason for this operation - if you want to write the result to a file, just do "objFile.WriteLine sRes".

Comment: all sorted, I was being a tool I just needed:
`objFile.WriteLine sRes`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(.*?)(?:\s*,){3}Yes\s*,Yes\r?
```

you need to take care of the linebreaks, with Regexr `\r` was fine. I put the line breaks into the regex because I wanted to have it optional using the `?` afterwards. Otherwise the last row will not be replaced if it does not end with a line break.

and replace it with

```
'$1',
```

Here you will get a additional comma at the end. I am at the moment not sure how to handle this.

`$1` is the content of the first capturing group, in your case the part before the first comma should be in it.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u1ss)

Comment: thanks for reply `strNewText = Replace(strText, "(.*?)(?:\s*,){3}Yes\s*,Yes\r?", "','")` doesn't appear to make any changes to the file?

Comment: @4rd2, you have to replace with `'$1',`, but if it does nothing it has not matched. Try replacing the `\r` with `\r\n` or `\n` to match the proper line break.